# problem of not a women's movement

Tags: meaning

> Like many of her associates, she believed that socialist development
> and class struggle were needed to solve society's problems, not a
> women's movement.

So, this one is the original sentence. At first, I thought that "not a women's movement" is a version omitting "to solve". that is, not to solve a women's movement. In that case, the whole sentence would be:

> Like many of her associates, she believed that socialist development
> and class struggle were needed to solve society's problems, not to
> solve a women's movement.

I understood it as the purpose of socialist development and class struggle is to solve society's problems, not to solve a women's movement. However, someone told me that the original sentence means that it's socialist development and class struggle, not a women's movement, that are needed to solve society's problems. But I couldn't understand why it could be interpreted in this way

Comment: How would you interpret 'You need a wrench to fix a car, not a garlic press'?

Comment: How did you get from "women's movement" to "women's problems"? You had to change the sentence to force it into your meaning that a women's movement needs solving.

Comment: In principle, the cited construction is inherently ambiguous. In practice, nearly everyone understands immediately that it doesn't make much sense to interpret it as meaning socialist development and class struggle were needed to resolve a women's movement. That would be a *perverse* (syntactically valid, but semantically nonsensical) interpretation.

Comment: @Michael Harvey that is obvious to see what it means. But in my case, both two interpretations seem logical to me...

Comment: can I understand you guys' words as "movements do not need to be solved, problems do and there is no such phrase as “solve movement” in English"?

Answer (score 2):

The correct interpretation could be written as follows:

> Like many of her associates, she believed that socialist development and class struggle, not a women's movement, were needed to solve society's problems.

"Not a women's movement" is in apposition to "socialist development and class struggle". The author decided to postpone the appositive; doing so is fairly common with longer appositives, but unfortunately it led to some ambiguity in this case. As you note, the sentence could be interpreted thus:

> Like many of her associates, she believed that socialist development and class struggle were needed to solve society's problems, not to solve a women's movement.

However, it would not make much sense for "socialist development and class struggle" to "solve a women's movement". Thus, it seems that there would be little reason for the author to place "not a women's movement" in apposition to "society's problems". The reader can, therefore, interpret the sentence correctly (perhaps after some initial confusion).